# DataTable export to PDF + asynchronously images = double files exported

Tags: javascript, datatable

I'm using DataTable and I have code that works basically fine. After clicking the button responsible for exporting table to PDF, a file with images is generated and downloaded, everything is great. The problem is (probably) that it happens asynchronously and two files are actually downloaded. One 'file-correct' with graphics and one 'file-invalid', without graphics. How can I change this so that only the correct file is downloaded? I removed some of the code for clarity.

I tried to add the code to live.datatables.net (https://live.datatables.net/noguvana/1/edit) but a lot of errors appear and the actual file-correct is not downloaded at all. It's strange, because these errors don't appear in the browser at all (in console) when I have the code on my site and the file-correct is exported (unfortunately with the file-invalid one).

I will mention that my programming knowledge is not so good. My code, I feel like it's sometimes a zombie product, which I put together and glue together from various code examples from the DataTable forum and Stack Oveflow.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
    const dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excel',
        }, {
            extend: 'pdf',
            title: 'file-invalid',
            async customize(doc) {
                if (doc) {
                    const fetches = [];
                    let imagesFetched = 0;

                    for (let i = 1; i < doc.content[1].table.body.length; i++) {
                        if (doc.content[1].table.body[i].length >= 6) {
                            const imageSrcElement = doc.content[1].table.body[i][5].text;
                            const parser = new DOMParser();
                            const docHTML = parser.parseFromString(imageSrcElement, 'text/html');
                            const imageSrc = docHTML.body.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');

                            const data = await fetchImage(imageSrc);
                            doc.content[1].table.body[i][5] = {
                                alignment: 'center',
                                image: data,
                                width: 60,
                            };
                            imagesFetched++;
                        }
                    }

                    await Promise.all(fetches);
                    pdfMake.createPdf(doc).download('file-correct.pdf');
                }
            }
        }],
    });

    function fetchImage(url) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          })
          .catch(reject);
      });
    }

    document.getElementById("export-pdf").addEventListener("click", function() {
        dataTable.button(1).trigger();
    });
       
});
```